# Assignments in if_else() vs. ifelse()

Tags: r, dplyr

As we were running our R intro workshop we covered the traditional roll dice example. However, one participant brought up an interesting challenge. The example below using `dyplr::if_else()` doesn't seem to work:

```
library(dplyr)
no_doubles <- TRUE
while (no_doubles) {
  dice<- sample(1:6,2,replace = TRUE)
  if_else(dice[1]==dice[2],no_doubles <- FALSE, no_doubles <- TRUE)
  print(dice)
}
```

However, using the base R `ifelse()` does:

```
library(dplyr)
no_doubles <- TRUE
while (no_doubles) {
  dice<- sample(1:6,2,replace = TRUE)
  ifelse(dice[1]==dice[2],no_doubles <- FALSE, no_doubles <- TRUE)
  print(dice)
}
```

The two example were variants of what I presented them:

```
library(dplyr)
no_doubles <- TRUE
while (no_doubles) {
  dice<- sample(1:6,2,replace = TRUE)
  if (dice[1]==dice[2]) no_doubles <- FALSE else no_doubles <- TRUE
  print(dice)
}
```

I had never tried to use an assignment in an `if_else()`/`ifelse()`, but does anyone know why the one works and the other doesn't?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with `dplyr::if_else` in the latest dplyr version.

Comment: This looks like a misuse of `ifelse/if_else`. You seen to be looking for logical control flow, not a vectorized transformation. You should be using an `if() {} else {}` statement here. The former statements will evaluate both true/false values in most cases so you'll be double assigning. Do not perform assignment inside the expression. Instead use it outside `no_doubles <- if_else(dice[1]==dice[2], FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: @TimTeaFan You mean you tested with `dplyr_1.0.9` and that while loop terminated? It did not for me.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing that @MrFlick pointed out (adding: also `data.table::fifelse()` does not stop the `while` loop).However I was wondering why this happens : `a <- 1; if_else(a == 1, example <- 'ok',example <-'ko'); example`. It prints the "correct" output, but it assigns to `example` the `else`.  Probably the example of the sleep of reason produces monsters (using `ifelse` instead of `if {}else {}`) :) ).

Comment: The `ifelse` happens to work because there's a special hack in it for tests of length 1. It's there because so many people misused the function rather than using the more appropriate `if/else` statement. The `dplyr` and `data.table `versions did not choose to include this hack and instead perform as such a function is intended to perform.

Comment: @MrFlick: I tested the assignment inside `dplyr::if_else`, which does not throw an error. The `while` loop however doesn’t terminate in the dev version of dplyr.

Comment: @TimTeaFan. Right. None of these throw an error. There's nothing wrong with the syntax; it's a problem with the logic. I think the OP was assuming that only one of the assignments in the `if_else` arguments would be evaluated, but that's not the case. Both arguments are evaluated which means `no_doubles` will always be TRUE with `if_else`